# Netbeans Swing jButton

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have two buttons and in the second one I want to use a variable made in the first button. So Netbeans is generating code of the button. ActionEvent generated by netbeans is 
"private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)"
and I cant change it. I tried to change button to public in button setting. I changed it to public but in code it is still private. I dont know what to do. Anyone know where the problem might be?
Thanks.

Comment: post your code and specify the error. You have to create your variable outside the button handler.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is, there is a blank line above the `private void buttonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)` you create your variable in that line the example: `int a;` now the a will turn green. This is called a global variable

Answer (score 0):

```
    JFrame jtfMainFrame;
    JButton jbnButton1, jbnButton2;
    JTextField jtfInput;
    JPanel jplPanel;
    //Declaring the string variable setText
    String setText;
    public JButtonDemo2() {
        jtfMainFrame = new JFrame("Which Button Demo");
        jtfMainFrame.setSize(50, 50);
        jbnButton1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        jbnButton2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        jtfInput = new JTextField(20);
        jplPanel = new JPanel();
        jbnButton1.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_I); //Set ShortCut Keys
        jbnButton2.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_I);




      jbnButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //Setting the setText variable
            setText = "Do whatever you want";
        }
    });

    jbnButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //Displaying the setText variable
            jtfInput.setText(setText);
        }
    });





        jplPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jplPanel.add(jtfInput);
        jplPanel.add(jbnButton1);
        jplPanel.add(jbnButton2);
        jtfMainFrame.getContentPane().add(jplPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jtfMainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jtfMainFrame.pack();
        jtfMainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare it as a global means when the class definition starts at that time declare the variable which you want to use at the two buttons click and change the value of variable according to your use.

Answer (score 0):

No need to change the **ActionPerformed()**. All you have to do is declare the variable as a **global variable** and then do whatever the task inside the button's ActionPerformed().